# c# добавление кнопок в форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма она разделена на 2 части. В левой создана кнопка. В правой tablelayoutpanel.При нажатии на кнопку должна заполняться tablelayoutpanel определённым количеством кнопок. К этим кнопкам добавить действие по клику и т.д. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего задать все кнопки изначально , добавив их в форму , и скрыть их , в последствии активировать отображение каждой из них и изменять ее свойство программно .

Comment: Реализовать в итоге хочу слева нажимаешь кнопку справа появляются другие.На каждой справа своё действие. Слева будут несколько кнопок.Каждая кнопка слева вызывает свои справа.

Comment: @OlegKolosovsky вы можете вызывать одни и те же кнопки, и просто менять их свойства , действия , текст , и прочее

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример создания кнопок, разберите его для понимания, и адаптируйте код под свои нужды.

```csharp
public partial class Form1:Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int _count = 0;
        Point location = new Point(0, 0);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button firstButton = new Button();
            firstButton.Name = "firstButton" + _count.ToString();
            firstButton.Text = "Button" + location.X.ToString() + ", " + location.Y.ToString();
            firstButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
            firstButton.Left = location.X;
            firstButton.Top = location.Y;
            firstButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            firstButton.Click += firstButtons_Click;
            panel1.Controls.Add(firstButton);


            if (_count == 5)
            {
                _count = 0;
                location = new Point(location.X + firstButton.Width);
            }
            else
            {
            _count++;
            location = new Point(location.X, location.Y + firstButton.Height);
            }
        }

        private void firstButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("You pressed the button " + btn.Text);
        }
    }
```